# Sistema de grid e input em css

Tags: html, css

Bom estou montando um grid e uns input, ontem postei um problema que estava tendo com o grid e o FERNANDOSAVIO me ajudou. Estou tendo um problema parecido quando tendo colocar os input dentro do grid. Sempre que termino uma linha ele cria um espaço maior. Alguém sabe o que pode ser? Já revirei o css e não consegui arrumar.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.form_campos').on('focus blur', function (e) {
        $(this).parents('.form-group').toggleClass('focused', (e.type === 'focus' || this.value.length > 0));
    }).trigger('blur');
    $('.select').on('change blur', function (e) {
        $(this).parents('.form-group-select').toggleClass('focused', (e.type === 'focus' || this.value !== ''));
    }).trigger('blur');

    $(".autofocus").trigger('focus');

    // Converte minusculas em maiusculas
    $('input').not('[name="link"]').on('input', function () {

        // Armazena posição corrente do cursor
        var start = this.selectionStart, end = this.selectionEnd;
        this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();

        // Restaura posição armazenada anteriormente.
        this.setSelectionRange(start, end);
    });
});
```

```css
/*====================================================================================================================*/
/* Input */
/*====================================================================================================================*/
.form-group {
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    height: 45px;
    float: left;
}
.control-label {
    opacity: 0.4;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate3d(5px, 22px, 0) scale(1);
    transform-origin: left top;
    transition: 240ms;
}
.form-group.focused .control-label, .form-group-select.focused .control-label {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(0.75);
}
.form_campos {
    height: 31px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #484848;
    align-self: flex-end;
    padding: 5px;
    outline: none;
    border: 0 solid #484848;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 0;
}
.form_campos:hover, .form_campos:focus {
    border-color: #0091FF;
}
.form_disabled, .form_disabled:hover, .form_disabled:focus {
    border-color: #D7D7D7;
}
/*====================================================================================================================*/
/* Select */
/*====================================================================================================================*/
.select {
    height: 31px;
    color: #484848;
    border-radius: 0;
    border: 0 solid #484848;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    margin-top: 14px;
    background: transparent;
    padding-right: 20px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}
.select:hover, .select:focus {
    border: 0 solid;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-color: #0091FF;
}
.form-group-select {
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    height: 45px;
    float: left;
}
.form-group-select:after {
    content:"\279C";
    color:#484848;
    transform:rotate(90deg);
    right:8px; 
    top:22px;
    position:absolute;
    pointer-events:none;
}
/*====================================================================================================================*/
/* Grid */
/*====================================================================================================================*/
.row {
    margin: 10px;
}

.row,
.column {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row:before,
.row:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.row:after {
    clear: both;
}
.column {
    float: left;
}
.row > .column:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.column + .column {
    margin-left: 1.6%;
}
.column-1 {
    width: 6.86666666667%;
}
.column-2 {
    width: 15.3333333333%;
}
.column-3 {
    width: 23.8%;
}
.column-4 {
    width: 32.2666666667%;
}
.column-5 {
    width: 40.7333333333%;
}
.column-6 {
    width: 49.2%;
}
.column-7 {
    width: 57.6666666667%;
}
.column-8 {
    width: 66.1333333333%;
}
.column-9 {
    width: 74.6%;
}
.column-10 {
    width: 83.0666666667%;
}
.column-11 {
    width: 91.5333333333%;
}
.column-12 {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0 !important;
}
/* Mobile */

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .column-1,
    .column-2,
    .column-3,
    .column-4,
    .column-5,
    .column-6,
    .column-7,
    .column-8,
    .column-9,
    .column-10,
    .column-11,
    .column-12 {
        width: auto;
        float: none;
    }
    .column + .column {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    .row {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .column {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .row:last-child .column:last-child {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
            <div class='form-group-select column column-4'>
                <label class='control-label'>GOSTOU?</label>
                <select name='gostou' class='select form_campos'>
                    <option value="s">SIM</option>  
                    <option value="n">NÃO</option>
                </select>       
            </div>
            <div class='form-group column column-8'>
                <label class='control-label' for='nome'>AQUI ELE CRIA UM ESPAÇO MAIOR</label>
                <input  type='text' class='form_campos' id='nome' name='nome'>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row">
            <div class='form-group column column-2'>
                <label class='control-label' for='data'>DATA</label>
                <input  type='text' class='form_campos data' id='data' name='data'>
            </div>
            <div class='form-group column column-2'>
                <label class='control-label' for='idade'>IDADE</label>
                <input  type='text' class='form_campos' id='idade' name='idade'>
            </div>
            <div class='form-group column column-8'>
                <label class='control-label' for='cidade'>CIDADE</label>
                <input  type='text' class='form_campos' id='cidade' name='cidade'>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe sua classe `.form_campos`, nela há um `height: 31px`, porém há também um `padding: 5px` e um `border-bottom-width: 1px`, ou seja, pega os 31px + 5px (top) + 5px (bottom) + 1px (border-bottom), que dá um total de 42px de altura, por isso ele cria esse "espaço maior".

Diminua o `height` dessa classe para que a soma da altura mais os *padding's* fiquem em um tamanho desejável.

No meu teste alterei para 20px de altura, assim o seu `input` terá uma altura total de 31px.

**EDIT:**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.form_campos').on('focus blur', function (e) {
        $(this).parents('.form-group').toggleClass('focused', (e.type === 'focus' || this.value.length > 0));
    }).trigger('blur');
    $('.select').on('change blur', function (e) {
        $(this).parents('.form-group-select').toggleClass('focused', (e.type === 'focus' || this.value !== ''));
    }).trigger('blur');

    $(".autofocus").trigger('focus');

    // Converte minusculas em maiusculas
    $('input').not('[name="link"]').on('input', function () {

        // Armazena posição corrente do cursor
        var start = this.selectionStart, end = this.selectionEnd;
        this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();

        // Restaura posição armazenada anteriormente.
        this.setSelectionRange(start, end);
    });
});
```

```css
/*====================================================================================================================*/
/* Input */
/*====================================================================================================================*/
.form-group {
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    height: 45px;
    float: left;
}
.control-label {
    opacity: 0.4;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate3d(5px, 22px, 0) scale(1);
    transform-origin: left top;
    transition: 240ms;
}
.form-group.focused .control-label, .form-group-select.focused .control-label {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(0.75);
}
.form_campos {
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #484848;
    align-self: flex-end;
    padding: 5px;
    outline: none;
    border: 0 solid #484848;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 0;
}
.form_campos:hover, .form_campos:focus {
    border-color: #0091FF;
}
.form_disabled, .form_disabled:hover, .form_disabled:focus {
    border-color: #D7D7D7;
}
/*====================================================================================================================*/
/* Select */
/*====================================================================================================================*/
.select {
    height: 31px;
    color: #484848;
    border-radius: 0;
    border: 0 solid #484848;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    margin-top: 14px;
    background: transparent;
    padding-right: 20px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}
.select:hover, .select:focus {
    border: 0 solid;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-color: #0091FF;
}
.form-group-select {
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    height: 45px;
    float: left;
}
.form-group-select:after {
    content:"\279C";
    color:#484848;
    transform:rotate(90deg);
    right:8px; 
    top:22px;
    position:absolute;
    pointer-events:none;
}
/*====================================================================================================================*/
/* Grid */
/*====================================================================================================================*/
.row,
.column {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row:before,
.row:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.row:after {
    clear: both;
}
.column {
    float: left;
}
.row > .column:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.column + .column {
    margin-left: 1.6%;
}
.column-1 {
    width: 6.86666666667%;
}
.column-2 {
    width: 15.3333333333%;
}
.column-3 {
    width: 23.8%;
}
.column-4 {
    width: 32.2666666667%;
}
.column-5 {
    width: 40.7333333333%;
}
.column-6 {
    width: 49.2%;
}
.column-7 {
    width: 57.6666666667%;
}
.column-8 {
    width: 66.1333333333%;
}
.column-9 {
    width: 74.6%;
}
.column-10 {
    width: 83.0666666667%;
}
.column-11 {
    width: 91.5333333333%;
}
.column-12 {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0 !important;
}
/* Mobile */

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .column-1,
    .column-2,
    .column-3,
    .column-4,
    .column-5,
    .column-6,
    .column-7,
    .column-8,
    .column-9,
    .column-10,
    .column-11,
    .column-12 {
        width: auto;
        float: none;
    }
    .column + .column {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    .row {
        /*margin-bottom: 10px;*/
    }
    .column {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .row:last-child .column:last-child {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class='form-group-select column column-4'>
    <label class='control-label'>GOSTOU?</label>
    <select name='gostou' class='select form_campos'>
      <option value="s">SIM</option>  
      <option value="n">NÃO</option>
    </select>       
  </div>
  <div class='form-group column column-8'>
    <label class='control-label' for='nome'>AQUI ELE CRIA UM ESPAÇO MAIOR</label>
    <input  type='text' class='form_campos' id='nome' name='nome'>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class='form-group column column-2'>
    <label class='control-label' for='data'>DATA</label>
    <input  type='text' class='form_campos data' id='data' name='data'>
  </div>
  <div class='form-group column column-2'>
    <label class='control-label' for='idade'>IDADE</label>
    <input  type='text' class='form_campos' id='idade' name='idade'>
  </div>
  <div class='form-group column column-8'>
    <label class='control-label' for='cidade'>CIDADE</label>
    <input  type='text' class='form_campos' id='cidade' name='cidade'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bom tentei aqui com 20PX e continuou do mesmo jeito, poderia editar sua resposta com o código alterado?

Comment: Veja acima o _EDIT_. Se não for isso, explique melhor por favor.

Comment: Bom acho que não expliquei o problema direito. Note que sempre que eu começo uma linha nova '<div class="row">' se cria uma espaço maior. repare que o input 'data' sem um espaço maior que os outros, pois é onde eu começo uma nova linha. quero deixar todos uniformes.

Comment: Observando no Developer Tools do Chrome, a classe `.row` tinha uma `margin: 10px`, ou seja, a cada nova linha, tinha esse espaçamento entre elas. Removi essa `margin` e também uma `margin-bottom: 10px` em uma _Media Query_. Veja se é isso agora. Caso precise verificar os estilos, abra o Developer Tools do Chrome e vá editando o CSS por lá mesmo, assim você tem uma noção do que acontece, depois só pegar as alterações e transferir para o seu código.

Comment: ok, deu era isso mesmo